# How to automatically add users to roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a small MVC4 web site and am using SimpleMembershipProvider along with the SimpleRoleProvider.

I have seeded my database so that the [webpages_Roles] contains "Administrator" and "User"
(similar to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548067/seeding-data-and-creating-managing-roles-in-mvc4-how-hard-can-it-be)).

Everything with the Accounts and User profile model is as it was when the MVC4 project was created.

Now how do I make it so that when ever someone registers they are automatically placed in the "User" role?

Comment: Are there any user created/registered event that I can listen for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically all your user registration logic will reside in your accounts controller (this is certainly the case if you use one of the provided templates for an Internet Application). Therefore you will need to add code to the registration method to add the user to the User role once their account is successfully created.

This is simpler and tidier than trying to watch for an event, even if one existed. You should find that in a well designed app you won't have your registration code in any more than a single place anyway. This also lets you handle OAuth scenarios, if you are using social network logins such as Facebook.

e.g. This is how you could use it with the out-of-the-box AccountsController in the Internet Application template (for your local site registration)

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ... various actions ...

    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register() {
        return View();
    }
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
// ----------------- NEW LINES HERE
                Roles.AddUserToRoles(model.UserName, new[] { "Users" });
// ----------------- END NEW LINES
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    ... more actions ...
}
```

Comment: That was too simple, Thanks. :)